# Checkbox CSS assistance or IE6 hack

Tags: html, css

Bad:

[image: IE6 ERROR WITH CHECKBOX]

Good:

[image: Good!]

The image above shows check-boxes parallel to eachother vertically, however this is IE6 and shows a noticeable error compared to other browsers.

The check-box has spacing almost like a margin around the perimeter of the box itself, in other browsers this does not exist but if there is a fix I would like to do so.

How would I remove the margin or fix this error in IE6 and possibly other browsers?

*EDIT*
I want a permanent fix that is compliant with any browser.

Comment: I honestly think a temporary fix will do.

Comment: Give us some code. Seriously, we can guess code from screenshots, but … No, we can’t. Especially the margins and paddings would interest me.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" id="delete[]" value="'.$record["id"].'" />

Comment: Both your HTML and your CSS code.

Comment: @BoltClock
Where in the code do you see class? Obviously there is no CSS for that individual tag.

Comment: @tjmoore1993: What about the surrounding code? Surely your checkboxes are in some other containing elements which do have associated CSS styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using a [CSS reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), you should. It will "reset" the default styles of browsers so you have a clean, identical slate to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your issue with the styling itself for the input tag, but to make separate CSS specifically for IE6 in the header tags place this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style>
    input {
        margin: 1px;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, not realizing IE6 handles a lot of thing improperly so this is what I used to fix the issue.

```
input {
    margin: 0;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you're not using a reset then the UA stylesheet *can* add arbitrary padding and margin to any element, so it may not be IE6 specific

Comment: This is emulating part of a reset stylesheet. See my answer.